# executable PassengerWatchdog not found

Tags: nginx, passenger

I just installed passenger with passenger-install-nginx-module and now when I try to start nginx I get the error that executable PassengerWatchdog not found.  The actual error says this:

```
executable (/home/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/passenger-3.0.19/agents/PassengerWatchdog) does not exist
```

I searched for PassengerWatchdog and its located here:

```
/home/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/passenger-4.0.5/agents/PassengerWatchdog
```

How and where do I change this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just realized where passenger_root is set.  It's in my nginx.conf file.